# Multi Tenant application not being able iterate through model

Tags: python, postgresql, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I am using this guide to create a multi-tenant application:
https://medium.com/@smirnov.am/multitenancy-with-flask-6f5375a34f55

The issue I am encountering is that the guide is doing this line:

```py
@simple_cache
def get_known_tenants():
    tenants = Tenant.query.all()
    return [i.name for i in tenants]
```

I am doing something similar here:

```py
def get_known_organizations():
    organizations = Organization.query.all()
    return [o.organization_name_url for o in organizations]
```

Am I missing something because the error I am getting is that:

`AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'query'`

Model

```
class Organization(db.Model):
    organization_id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    cypher = db.Column(db.String(10), unique=True, nullable=False)                  # 10-character String representation to use as ID of the organization
    organization_name = db.Column(db.String(100), unique=True, nullable=False)      # Organization name as String (ex: Seattle Children's Hospital)
    organization_name_url = db.Column(db.String(100), unique=True, nullable=False)  # Parsed organization name to lowercase and with dashes to use as subdomain (ex: seattle-childrens-hospital)
    website = db.Column(db.Text, unique=True, nullable=False)                       # URL of the organization's website
    contact_phone = db.Column(db.String(15), unique=True, nullable=False)           # Organization's contact number
    ooo_phone = db.Column(db.String(15), unique=True, nullable=False)               # Omedyari number
```

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue, it seems like when I go to a url that doesn't not have that specific data base in postgres, it is not able to iterate through it.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you missed @simple_cache before defining method. Or Organization variable is updated at any instance to other None value.